# Foundation 5 how to make one column for small screen

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I have the following grid using [zurb-foundation](/questions/tagged/zurb-foundation):

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="small-6 large-3 columns">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="small-6 large-9 columns">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

The above grid makes the layout of two columns. However, I want to know in small screens to make the above layout to be one column layout instead of two columns with 6. In other words, I want the second div of that row to act as a new row for small screens.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using the standard 12 column grid and haven't modified that, just make the small ones 12:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="small-12 large-3 columns">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="small-12 large-9 columns">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Just know that small filters it's way up... so in this example "medium" will also be 12.  If you want medium to look like large, then do this:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="small-12 medium-9 columns">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Notice how you don't need the large in the above example as medium filters up to  everything above it.

Answer (score 1):

using the below Html you can have offset and have centered div on mobile screen.and have large-3 and large-9 div respectively on larger screens.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-6 small-offset-3 large-3 large-offset-0 columns ">..</div>
  <div class="new small-6 small-offset-3 large-9 large-offset-0 columns">..</div>
</div>
```

In foundation css column last child is floated right.so we change it to float left to have both the div stacked up on after the other

```
.new{
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-6 large-3 columns">
        <div class="small-6 medium-12 large-12 columns">column 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-6 large-9 columns">
        <div class="small-6 medium-12 large-12  columns">column 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6tMZH/

Comment: This would make the columns occupy 100% space on small screens.He wants to have them with a small-6 column structure

Comment: @JAre Does it allowed in Foundation 5 to make columns without parent row? I mean the inner `small-6 medium-12 large-12 columns` ?

Comment: @sємsєм To be sure you can add one extra wrapper with the `row` class but in this case it looks ok.

Answer (score -1):

should be a simple fix:

```
.columns {
    width:100%;
}
```

[**You can see it here**](http://jsfiddle.net/asapmmeehan/gLaLC/)